# How to differentiate AnyObject (or Int) type in XCode 9 - new Swift compiler

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, xcode9, swift4

I need to check the type of AnyObject that was given an Int (or Int16 or UInt8) value, i.e.

In Xcode 8 - switching over the object, using cases:
`is Uint8`, `is Int16`, `is Int` works pefrect.
In Xcode 9 - It always enter the first case that is ***possibly*** true.

Here is a code sample for Playground:

```
var t1: AnyObject?
var t2: AnyObject?

t1 = 30 as AnyObject
t2 = Int16(30) as AnyObject

if let obj1 = t1 {
    switch obj1 {
    case is UInt8:
        print("UInt8")
    case is Int16:
        print("Int16")
    case is Int:
        print("Int")
    default:
        break
    }
}

if let obj2 = t2 {
    switch obj2 {
    case is UInt8:
        print("UInt8")
    case is Int16:
        print("Int16")
    case is Int:
        print("Int")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

XCode 8 playground console prints:
Int
Int16

XCode 9 playground console prints:
UInt8
UInt8

A. Can someone explain why, and/or attached any documeted reference regarding this?
B. Would be happy I someone can help me acheive same functionality in XCode 9.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Swift 3 all numeric types are `Any`, not `AnyObject`

```
var t1: Any?
var t2: Any?

t1 = 30 as Any
t2 = Int16(30) as Any
...
```

This solves the issue.

I suppose casting to `AnyObject` bridges the type to `NSNumber` which matches any case.

Comment: Bridging to NSCFNumber is exactly what's happening. Found out this by printing `type(of:)` of obj

Comment: I think so. `AnyObject` is any class type and `Intxx` is not a class. Casting as `AnyObject` must, therefore, turn it into a `NSNumber`.